# Convert formatted string to text

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to deal with pasted texts such as '' in my wordpress site.
I'd like to convert all the strings formatted like this to simple plain text.
I've seen that "pasting text without formatting" option doesn't work and it seems like there aren't any plugins that solve this problem
Can you help me finding a way?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I mean something like what [yaytext.com](https://yaytext.com/unstyle/) does

Comment: "pasting text without formatting" does not work, because this _is not_ "formatting." These are completely different _characters_ - that `` is not an `N`. You want to go look for something that can "translate" this into normal latin characters.

Comment: thanks @CBroe  
at the moment I've embedded the yaytext service like this:
`function text_cleaner() { add_meta_box('id_metabox', 'Text cleaner', 'metabox_content', array('post', 'page'), 'normal', 'default' );}  
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'text_cleaner');
function metabox_content($post) {echo '<iframe src="https://yaytext.com/unstyle/" width="100%" height="300"></iframe>';}`  
I'll keep looking for a better solution